# I am looking for code policy enforcement tool for xml and Python

Tags: continuous-integration, static-analysis

I have projects that are developed with `xml` and `python` code mostly (Odoo modules). There is a bit of `.po` files for translation and `csv` fields for data.

I would like to enforce specific policies in `xml` files, for example:

- No duplicate id attributes.
- A specific attribute must be present if child elements contain a specific tags.

On python, I want to enforce rules like:

- Look for SQL queries, and make sure that they use specific parameter methods to prevent SQL injection
- Follow a specific naming convention
- Some attributes are required in classes that inherit a specific class

I hope that the idea is clear.

Is there any open source solution for this? Preferably linked with github and checks on every commit!

Answer (score 0):

I found a python package made specifically for this, `pylint-odoo`, [here](https://github.com/OCA/pylint-odoo).

It can also be installed with `pip install pylint-odoo`.

An example `.pylintrc` config file can be found at the web OCA module, [here](https://github.com/OCA/web/blob/14.0/.pylintrc). They also have another file named `.pylintrc-mandatory`.

There is even a warning for duplicate xml `id` attribute `W7902`.